# Is there anyway Express in Node.js can have more than one static folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, static, express

I'm working on a project where there is a user uploaded collection of styles, scripts and images and then their is my app's collection of styles, scripts and images. They're two different places on my server.

Is there anyway I can setup Express in Node.js so it can more than one static folder? I'm wanting it to serve both - obviously, I'd make sure of directory and file name conflicts. Is that even possible?

The way I have for one static folder at this moment is like this:

```
this.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

...but I'm wanting to directories for static files.

Or is there totally different another way I could achieve this?

Thanks, James

Comment: You could just use subdirectories of the single static folder.

Comment: Yes, a good approach would be to just have one static folder with subfolders in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
this.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public1'));
this.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public2'));
```

The first one will have priority with regards to filenames.

Comment: I should of tried that really. Many thanks. So simple! (I wanted to ask, because I wanted to make sure it's the right way and others can find out too.)